# Creating a vector in order to measure distance from a sprite to another vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I'm currently just starting to create a game with Pyglet featuring a race car, which will drive around a track, of which I intend to later add Tensorflow.

Is there any way which I can draw a vector from a certain position on the car (i.e the back, front or right hand side)?  I would then ideally be able to measure the distance from the side of the track in that direction through a vector I will set on the side, not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What have you tried so far? What specifically isn't working?

Comment: This is strictly a math problem, so you're essentially asking "Can I calculate the distance between two points with math?". There for, the answer is.. yes! You can.

Comment: When you say *"can draw a vector from a certain position on the car"*, then do you mean to draw an arrow by the use of OpenGL/pyglet or do you just want to calculate the direction vector between 2 points?